# Changing the location nautilus mounts samba shares to

Tags: nautilus, samba, gvfs

I would like to change the way nautilus mounts my shared windows folders.

Currently the path to my shared folder is:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=some.cool.server,share=someshare/path/to/my/files
```

But for some programs having `.`, `,`, `:` and `=` in the filename isn't cool.

Thus I would like to change the mount point such that my path would be more along the lines of

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/someshare/path/to/my/files
```

Is this possible?

I've asked questions on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969699/the-matlab-h5write-function-cannot-write-to-shared-windows-folder-mounted-thro) and [The mathworks forum](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/425834-h5write-on-gvfs-shared-folder-windows-shared-folder-connected-to-linux-pc) on how to use the program with the standard gvfs path

Comment: If you want other location, use `mount` command or `fstab` file to mount Samba shares. Or simply quote the path to use it in programs, than you have no issues. You could also create symbolic links. In general, I think you should stick with the path that gvfs provides and rather ask a question on how to use that path with a program you're having problems with.

Comment: @RoVo I would much rather keep the path gvfs provided, And I have asked questions on how to use the program with them. This is more of a "Second hand solution"